# How to change the assembly code %hi and %lo to run in 'MARS'?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I used 'compiler explorer' to convert c++ to MIPS
but it doesn't work well in the MARS because of %hi and %lo

I know I should change the part, but I don't know how to change...

Please help

```
$L5:
        lui     $2,%hi($LC1)
        lwc1    $f0,%lo($LC1+4)($2)

        lwc1    $f1,%lo($LC1)($2)
        b       $L3
$LC1:
        .word   1100470148
        .word   0
```

```
$L17:
        lw      $2,16($fp)
        addiu   $3,$2,1
        sw      $3,16($fp)
        lui     $4,%hi(savepath)
        sll     $3,$2,2
        addiu   $2,$4,%lo(savepath)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        li      $3,1                        # 0x1
        sw      $3,0($2)
        move    $sp,$fp
        lw      $fp,36($sp)
        addiu   $sp,$sp,40
        j       $31
```

Comment: Use `la` to load an address. Don't post your question repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way in Mars to have something like the gas %lo(label) or %hi(label) feature.
A simple workaround is to use the standard macro `la` that loads a label in a register with a pair or `lui`/`ori` instructions.

The first part of your code can be rewritten like that:

```
$L5:
        la      $2, $LC1
        lwc1    $f0,4($2)
        lwc1    $f1,0($2)
        b       $L3
$LC1:
        .word   1100470148
        .word   0
```

As the `la` macro is expanded to two instructions,that is an extra instruction compared to the use of  `%hi/%lo` but it works.

Comment: This might be the best you can do in MARS without hard-coding numeric addresses, but it wastes an instruction assuming `la` expands to `lui` + `ori` or `addiu`.  The original was able to use the 16-bit immediate of the addressing mode for the low halves of the addresses.

Comment: You can do stuff like `lwc1 $f0,  label($zero)`  in MARS, and you can select a memory model where `.data` starts at address `0` so a 16-bit immediate is sufficient.  (But the assembler may well expand every such load using an `lui` if it doesn't know that the address is small when assembling.)